# article below 5 letter is saving when its not meant to save on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

am following ruby on rails documentation, and my title isn't suppose to save if it is bellow 5 letters, but mine is saving.
can someone please tell me what i got wrong, and how i can fix it.

here is my article.rb

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
 validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

my articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end


def new
  @article = Article.new
end

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
 end
```

and my new.html.erb

```
<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

And is Documentation a good way of learning ruby as a beginner? or recommend any tutorial video.

Comment: Can you please check the log and paste in comment what title params value you pass to save the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
 validates :title, presence: true
 validates_length_of :title, :minimum => 5
end
```

[more example here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: @OmiyeraDamilola feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you .